# Dojo wysiwyg editor and Django template

Tags: html, django, dojo, editor, wysiwyg

I've added the Dojo wysiwyg editor to my django admin panel.  I have an issue when I type more than one space.  When I output the syntax created by the editor to a template I get `&amp;nbsp;` for each extra space.  I assume it's trying to create a non-breaking space, but it renders in the browser as `&nbsp;`.

Does anyone know why this is?  How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I think its django who is changng `&` to `&amp;` on serverside. If its was a simple space django would have replaced it with `&nbsp;` by itself. I donno if there is any feature to turn off escaping for is specific case in django you can try that.

Comment: Yeah this is defenitly on the serverside.  It's changing all html <p>5</p> outputs like this: `&lt;p&gt;5&lt;/p&gt;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research you want to use the template filter [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to fix this issue.  You'll probably also want to add the filter [removetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#removetags) with script as an option to remove potentially malicious javascript.  So my template variable ends up looking like this: `{{ var|removetags:"script"|safe }}`

Answer (score 0):

I think its django who is changing `&` to `&amp;` on serverside. If its was a simple space django would have replaced it with `&nbsp;` by itself. I donno if there is any feature to turn off escaping for is specific case in django you can try that